# Error to find the first no repeated char in Java

Tags: java, algorithm, loops, char

I have a strange issue to print the first non repeated character from String.

If I put for example "sasso" as String it gives me back correctly: 'a'

but if I try with "sassa" I wonder why it gives me back: "s"

```
public class FirstChar {

public char findFirst(String s) {

    boolean[] letters = new boolean[26];
    char[] firstLetter = new char[26];

    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {

        if (letters[s.charAt(i) - 97] && 
                (firstLetter[0] != (s.charAt(i)))) {

            System.out.println( firstLetter[0]);
            return firstLetter[0];          
        }
        letters[s.charAt(i) - 97] = true;
        char c = (char) (s.charAt(i));
        firstLetter[i] = c;
    }
    System.out.println(firstLetter[1]);
    return firstLetter[1];
}
public static void main(String args[]) {
    FirstChar obj = new FirstChar();
    obj.findFirst("sassa");
}
```

}

Comment: For `"sassa"`, what did you expect? Do you know which of the `'s'` characters is returned? Have you tried stepping through the code line by line in a debugger? Maybe you should?

Comment: I expect: 'a' as first no repeated char

Comment: So by "repeating" you mean "*consecutively* repeating"? You still should try to step through the code in a debugger to see what it does.

Comment: If @Someprogrammerdude, right about "consecutively repeating" when it should be 's' in both test cases.

Comment: There are problems in this method apart from the question here.  As long as there are no repeating characters, you always get the second char. So "soup" returns "o."  "abcdefghijklmnop" returns "b."    As long as there IS a repeating character, you always get the *first char*.  So "abcdefgghijklmnop" returns "a."  "aaabcdefgghijklmnop" also returns "a," even though "a" is repeating.  Step through the code and carefully evaluate what it's doing and what you expect it to do.

Comment: Your specification is incomplete:  It says to print the first non-repeated character, but it does not say what the program is supposed to do when there is _no such character_.  This kind of thing happens to software developers all the time.  It's what we call an [edge case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edge_case).  One of the more difficult aspects of software development is identifying and deciding how to handle all of the different edge cases and [corner cases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corner_case) that are implicit in a seemingly simple problem specification.

Comment: @jameslarge: this is the exercise third exercise of those: [here](http://javarevisited.blogspot.co.uk/2015/01/top-20-string-coding-interview-question-programming-interview.html) I am trying to have practice with algorithms, of course without look at the solutions :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to ensure that firstLetter acts as a queue of non repeating characters and remove from it, the moment repeated character is encountered. You are always returning character at 0th or 1st position without overwriting firstLetter array elements.
In case is `sassa`, when last character `a` is encountered, conditions in first `if` evaluate to true and thus return `s` which is the first character stored in the firstLetter array.
You need HashMap and Queue to achieve this

Comment: you are right! I think that for me is time to start studying the Collections.